# Image upload in Ruby on Rails using remotipart gem and Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, remotipart

I am having a form submit in which the user can be able to choose multiple images( choosing one by one ) not multiple enabled in file field.

When the user chooses the image I will add an image tag for image preview and hidden file field for each of the images added.

When the validation fails in back end it just removes a file field. This removes a file field for each time when validation error occurs(any field validation). Anything better can be done for this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you show preview before image file being uploaded, follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

**note**: will not work in IE8(fileReader is supported from IE10).

Comment: I have added preview and I need to allow the user to upload many images, When the form gets submitted using remotipart(while validation error occurs) it deletes the added hidden field

Comment: try using class variable so that it stores values and you can access in view although validations fails.